# Using PowerQuery how can you ignore a scheduled refresh if the API you're calling is unavailable?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am calling an API with PowerQuery in PowerBI desktop with the intention of pushing the data into the online service for scheduled refreshing.

The query itself works as intended but will throw an error if the API service is unavailable. This proves a problem as the whole scheduled refresh will fail if one of one query doesn't work.

I've thrown a try...otherwise around the call but I don't know how to tell it to skip the current query if it returns an error.

```
let
    url = "https://example-api.com",
    .
    . <code omitted for brevity>
    .
    AddColumns =  try Table.AddColumn(CreateTable, 
                                      "Data", 
                                      each Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, 
                                                                          [                                                                                                                                       
                                                                            Headers =[#"Accept"="application/json"],                                                                                                  
                                                                            Timeout=#duration(0, 0, 10, 0),
                                                                            RelativePath="/api/index.php/api-method.json",
                                                                            Query=
                                                                                  [
                                                                                    #"filter" = "openedDate $gte 2016-03-01T00:00:00", 
                                                                                    #"key" = "<api-key>", 
                                                                                    #"select" = "customerId,type,status,name,userId,total,openedDate",
                                                                                  ]
                                                                          ]
                                                                      ))),
in
    AddColumns
```

The best outcome here would be if it catches an error to cancel the current query and keep the data from the last successful data refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I'd move *try* keyword after *each*. This will leave row, when your variant would fail the whole table.

```
AddColumns =  Table.AddColumn(CreateTable, 
                                  "Data", 
                                  each try Json.Document(skipped d/l code) otherwise null
                                  ),
DataTable = if Table.IsEmpty(Table.SelectRows(AddColumns, each [Data] <> null)) then OldTableWithData else AddColumns,
NextStep = DoSomething(DataTable),
etc etc
```

Also this article might prove useful for you:
http://blog.gbrueckl.at/2013/12/error-handling-in-power-query/